# Access denied for user 'homestead@localhost' .. in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I use the command php artisan migrate to migrate my db in laravel 5 ..
it gives me an error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: Have you checked the correct password is being used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [problems with database connection in laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389697/problems-with-database-connection-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Please see my answer in the question I posted above, you need to change the values for your connection in the .env file

Comment: You may Follow the below link :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes/30340330#30340330)

Answer (score 9):

Sometime in the future.  Try to clear your config first

```
php artisan config:clear.
```

Close all the terminal /cmd windows and then restart terminal/CMD and this should get rid of the error message. See if it works.

Answer (score 4):

In your Laravel .env file, alter the variables accordingly to match your desired settings.

If you're using something like XAMMP or EasyPHP with a mysql db, perhaps use the following setup

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_DATABASE=mysql
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=''
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have all your configurations ok in the **.env file** then you should:

In **Terminal** run this command that lists processes with `php` in it:

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

then:

> 501  **4529**   599   0 Sat03PM ttys000    0:00.15 php artisan serve
>
> 501  **4533**  4529   0 Sat03PM ttys000    0:25.11 /usr/bin/php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ds7/laravel/coffeeshop/server.php

Use the `kill` command to terminate the process (Notice: The process id is the second column group of numbers.)

```
kill 4529
kill 4533
```

Then run `php artisan config:clear`

Finally, restart server with:

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  'mysql' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => 'laravel',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'PASSWORD IF HAVE OTHERWISE LEAVE IT BLANK ',
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
            ],
```

**REMOVE THE ENV values from db,host and password and put them  direct**

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked several times before .. checkout the best answers I found :

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475762/setting-up-laravel-on-a-mac-php-artisan-migrate-error-no-such-file-or-directory/25649930#25649930)

The problems behind this error could be :

- Your .env file and config/database.php are incorrect.
- You didn't set the correct `unix_socket` value in your config file, checkout [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475762/setting-up-laravel-on-a-mac-php-artisan-migrate-error-no-such-file-or-directory/25649930#25649930).
- You are trying to run the `php artisan migrate:install` from your local machine. You should SSH into the VM `homestead ssh` and run your migrations from there, checkout [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes).

Answer (score 0):

in your database.php file, take off `'DB_DATABASE'
                   'DB_USERNAME'
                   'DB_PASSWORD'`

and replace with your database name, username and password

this will work fine for u.

Answer (score 0):

Edit .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yourdbname
DB_USERNAME=yourusername
DB_PASSWORD=yourpassword
```

and type in your cmd

```
php artisan migrate
```

it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file
change DB_PORT from

```
DB_PORT=3306
```

to

```
DB_PORT=33060
```

refrence to https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#connecting-to-databases

becarefull about last zero

Answer (score 0):

Two way to solve it

Open your database config file (laravel_root/config/database.php) & search for the below code block.

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'blog'),
'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

Change the code block as below

```
'host'      => 'enteryourHostName',
'database'  => 'ebterYourDatabastName',
'username'  => 'enterYoutDatabaseUsername',
'password'  => 'enterYourDatabasePassword',
```

Second way (Recommended by Laravel)

Check your Laravel root there have a file call .env if not exist, look for .env.example, copy/rename it as .env after that the file looks blow !

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=someRandomNumber

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

Modify the below block as follow

```
DB_HOST=yourHostName
DB_DATABASE=yourDatabaseName
DB_USERNAME=yourDatabaseUsername
DB_PASSWORD=youPassword
```

This Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Once you changed your .env file then you must restart the server.

In laravel in command prompt, type:

```
php artisan serve
```