# How can i fix This error (PDOException in Connector.php line 55) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just a beginner of laravel and when an trying to Work with models just that error pop up
and the exact error message is :

PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Here is my route code :

```
 route::get('customer', function(){
    $customer = App\customer::find(1);
    echo $customer->name;
    });
```

and here is my .env file

```
 APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:YP84cuDiwIkv4iCqrEEWMQBdOklL2+coODVf9qB6HwY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=my password

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: WHat is exact error message?

Comment: make sure your username and password is correct, and if you can edit your question with the exact message error

Comment: i have done editing my question with exact error message

Comment: Is your password actually my password with a space? if so wrap it in ' ' 
DB_PASSWORD='my password'

Comment: No that's not my reall password 
 there is real password but i don't wanna put it here

Comment: Try the solutions from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes

Comment: Thanks so much the first answer help me and now my problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

For this issue please do following steps -

```
1. php artisan config:clear
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan serve
```

If it is still not working then make changes in config/database.php as -

```
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
    'strict' => false,
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem. I started my server using php artisan serve command, and edited the .env file and refreshed the web-page which did not reflect any changes!

I fixed it by stopping the webserver, editing the .env.php file and restarting the webserver!

So I guess it's a caching-issue of the .env.php file.