# PDOException SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant

I am new in Laravel 5.2.

I am getting following error:

```
[PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (usin
 g password: YES)
```

While I execute following command:

```
 php artisan migrate
```

I am running application using vagrant on windows PC.
Please let me know why I am getting above error.

Comment: Are you firing this command from your virtual machine, or from your host machine? In other words, did you make a `vagrant ssh` before making this command?

Comment: yes, I am executing above command from virtual machine

Comment: This error was due to `caching-issue` of the `.env.php` file cause Laravel 5 is using environment based configuration in your `.env`file. You can find the answer in this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting above error because on your .env file. If you open that from your project base directory then you will following default configuration:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Just change above values according to your development environment. Try again, Hopefully that would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the database connection in .env file.