# Can't fix access denied for user homestead in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating my very first project and I want to use my local php environment instead of Hemestead.
I created the project and now I have to create the database. I'mtrying to follow the steps of this link "https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart" and want to execute this command: php artisan migrate.
When executing I take this error:

> Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I read this: [Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes)
but I don't understand something. What to put instead of:

```
DB_HOST=yourHostName
DB_DATABASE=yourDatabaseName
DB_USERNAME=yourDatabaseUsername
DB_PASSWORD=youPassword
```

So how to find my database name, hostname etc?
I repeat I am not using Homestead.

Comment: You need to put your database credentials. That's something you'd create when you create the database user. Check your local environment documentation, or read up on how to create a user in for mysql or whatever database you're using.

Comment: If not Homestead, what kind of dev environment are you using? Vagrant? MAMP? Installed Apache & MySQL yourself?

Comment: yes I fixed it. I have installed Apache and mysql. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be sure that you have `homestead` db in your *`phpmyadmin`*. If don't, please create a new one. And than, go to .env file (this is the default of mysql) fill your username database with root, and the password is (empty). I had a same problem with you about 1 or 2 months ago. I just created a new one db because I have no `homestead` db in my phpmyadmin. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not change anything in your homestead configuration, those are the values

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestad
DB_USERNAME=homestad
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

If you are not sure about it, SSH into your homestead box and try to login using

```
mysql -uhomestead -psecret
```

Also try

```
mysql -uroot -psecret
```

And if it works you have to change them to

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestad
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

If it doesn't login, you probably will have to recover your MySQL password:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html