# Access denied for user ‘dbuser’

Tags: php, laravel

In order to create a database, I run the command in terminal: 
php artisan migrate

I get this:

```
SQLSTATE [HY00] [1045] Access denied for user ‘dbuser’@‘localhost’ (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.table where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)
```

I’ve ran the command `php` artisan `config:cache` and it was successful but I still can’t seem to configure `phpMyAdmin` to connect to database? How can I solve this error?

Comment: show your code for configuration

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes

Comment: Do u have such user with his password

Comment: i just took a look at the link. question: ‘laravelu’ ? i named my project Blog so should i type laravel-blog? or laravelblog

Answer (score 0):

After making any configuration related changes in `.env` or to files in `config` directory,

**You need to run:**

```
$ php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: i ran the command and when i run php artisan migrate i still get the same error

Comment: @pinealda check if your credentials are correct

Comment: which file do i check my credentials?

Comment: the DB credentials in your `.env `file @pinealda, Hostname username and password

Comment: i have laravel-woke as database and I have ’dbuser’ and ‘123’  so where should it supposed to match? it just seem like phpMyAdmin is not connected.. I can’t find the database in there

Comment: @pinealda I am sorry I cannot verify your credentials, but it is surely the problem. Please verify they are correct