# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user mimi_oboss

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I get this error  when trying connect to the server.

> Access denied for user mimi_oboss'@'49.222.181.101' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `categories`)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mimi.mysql.tool
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mimi_oboss
DB_USERNAME=mimi_oboss
DB_PASSWORD=^oboss123
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29756194/2693543

Comment: Thanks but those are only for test purpose@Qirel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must turn off server and turn on when change `.env`  file , just restart the server

Comment: then I try php artisan config/cache clear also nothing changed

Comment: Are you sure for `DB_HOST` ?

Comment: Yes@Ahmad Abo Zaid

Comment: I think the `DB_HOST` must be a  domain or ip address !

Comment: After change into IP address 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.'

Comment: Yes , this is because the server not response anything , you must check the server